# Python Autobahn websocket messages delayed

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, twisted, autobahn

my autobahn websocket server is delaying messages and sending at the same time.

For example;

```py
while 1:
   self.sendMessage(struct.pack("<BHHfffI",4,300,2,1,100,100,1),True)
   time.sleep(0.010)
```

in this example, client will receive 7-8 messages at same time. (0.5-1s delay)

How can i send messages normally? i want to send a binary message every 10ms.

### Solution

I've changed it to

```
self.sendMessage(struct.pack("<BHHfffI",4,300,2,1,100,100,1),True)
reactor.callLater(0.01, self.resend)
```

and it's working normally now. Original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38881433/python-autobahn-websocket-messages-delayed?noredirect=1#comment65172396_38881433).

Comment: can't have blocking code like ``time.sleep(n)`` in async code unless it's in a thread.  Consider using ``reactor.callLater()`` or ``task.LoopingCall()``.

Comment: Thanks, it's working normally now.